# cURL working through terminal, not through PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have been trying to use the [AIDA disambiguation service](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/aida/webservice/). Their posted cURL example works fine through the terminal. However, when I try to implement it through PHP, I get an empty response immediately. To top it all off, I'm trying to access this resource essentially from Javascript, but as far as I've found, going through PHP is the best way to access resources from another domain.

My PHP code:

```
<?php 
//set POST variables
$url = $_POST['url'];
unset($_POST['url']);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$_POST);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$a = curl_exec($curl);
error_log('Status: '.var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl)));
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

The curl_getinfo:

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(56) "https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/aida/service/disambiguate"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.125)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.063)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(12) "139.19.87.30"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
```

`$a` is just empty. `$url` is set properly. The only other variable, `text`, seems to be set properly as well. Anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

with something like that i have the answer from AIDA web service.
In $result post the text you want to disambiguate.

```
<?php
$url = "https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/aida/service/disambiguate";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "text='".$result."'"); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$a = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($a);

?>
```

I hope that will help you